# Quicklisp: Archive is the wrong size

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

I'm trying to use the cl-heap library, but when I run

```
(quicklisp:quickload 'cl-heap)
```

it returns:

```
The archive file "cl-heap-0.1.6.tgz" for "cl-heap" is the wrong size: expected 26,979, got 12,288
```

What can I do to be able to run cl-heap?

Comment: Are you sure the download isn't interrupted by a network problem?

Comment: which implementation are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure that this means that your downloaded file is broken.  Maybe the download was interrupted, or your disk is full.

Retry by calling `ql:uninstall` on the system first, make sure that you have enough disk space and a working network connection, then `ql:quickload` again.

Comment: The problem really was with the downloaded file but ql:uninstall didn't work because the package hadn't been installed.

However, SBCL gave me the option to remove the file (wich I wasn't finding) and repeat the download, fixing the problem.